# Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-mix\bin\cli.js

Tags: vue.js

i have an error " Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-mix\bin\cli.js' " when i try to run
npm run watch command for new laravel vue js project.
i also try to remove node_modules and package-lock.json file and reinstall npm 2 - 3 time but i cant resolve this error then please help me

Comment: check the path of node in system variable. Make sure its's pointing to the current path of node in system,

Comment: all variable path are ok